# Will a constant remain the same between iOS updates?

Tags: iphone, ios, constants, plist

There is a constant I'm using from the iOS SDK. I printed out the value of the constant (which were int's) and it was 0. Can I assume that constant will always remain zero between iOS builds? The reason I need to use the actual value and not the constant directly is because I want to keep it in a plist that ships in the main bundle. And since a plist doesn't take a constant variable name, I need to place a constant value in the plist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't assume an enum won't change its value, just to be safe, even though it probably won't. (They'll almost certainly keep it constant so old apps run correctly on future OS versions.)

Instead, save a string to your plist (say, "standard" under the key "map type"), and then initialize the actual value at runtime with an if statement. This has the added benefit of actually saying what you mean explicitly, which makes it easier to look at your plist (and your code!) and see what it does.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm doing, I was hoping to reduce the if statements, but I guess to make sure the app will remain compatible I should keep them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that it will stay the same for at least the life of your application, if not longer.